8 week old Kitten with shifted fracture, what would happen if we let it heal like this?
I'm getting a new kitten from my cousin and it broke its leg at last Thursday.
The fracture as seen in the xray is shifted and the correction would cost 2500€. I wasn't at the doctors so I don't know what he said exactly but I'd just like to have someone else take a look at it and tell me what could happen if left like it is right now without correcting it


I'm not a vet, but I don't see how this bone could ever heal without being set and stabilized.

if you leave this as it is now your cat will be in pain for the rest of his/her life,please don`t let this happen.

There are options here, but doing nothing is not one of them. The kitten is young, and this would probably heal in some abnormal way, but the cat would likely be left with either long term discomfort or inability to normally use the leg. With the fracture being quite oblique, it would be difficult to stabilize this for it to heal normally, without surgery.
Options:

Surgical stabilization - likely to heal well at this age.
Amputation - this is a reasonable option which would likely be significantly less cost. Cats generally do well with three legs, but obviously this is not the ideal plan as this leg may quite easily be saved with surgery.
Surrender kitten to rescue group who may be able to fix the fracture or amputate.
Attempt to stabilize with splint, with expectation this will not heal completely normally. The vet might not think this is possible to splint, depending on the other x-ray views. The humerus can be difficult to splint with a lot of motion from the shoulder. Keeping the kitten confined will be difficult. That being said, the kitten is young, and there is a chance it might heal okay. This will take many weeks of strict rest, pain medication, and nursing care, and probably longer healing than either surgical option. May require amputation if not successful.

